# NATS with moleculer. How can I change NATS max_payload value?

Tags: javascript, docker, nats.io, runatserver, moleculer

My problem is that I need to increase max_payload value that NATS receive but I have no idea where I can do it.

The project is using Moleculer and NATS is created as a container with docker.

---

When I try to make a request which is bigger than 1MB NATS returns:

```
ERROR - NATS error. 'Maximum Payload Violation
```

Inside dockstation logs NATS returns:

```
cid:1 - maximum payload exceeded: 1341972 vs 1048576
```

---

I tried the following items:

- Changing tranporter inside Moleculer Broker configs (https://moleculer.services/docs/0.12/transporters.html);
- Add an config file for NATS to modify some options (https://hub.docker.com/_/nats);

Code example of Moleculer Broker configs:

```
const brokerConfig: BrokerOptions = {
  ...,
  transporter: "NATS",
  transit: {
    maxQueueSize: 100000,
    disableReconnect: false,
    disableVersionCheck: false,
  },
  ...
}
```

Code example of nats config file:

```
{
  max_payload: 1000000
}
```

---

Error when I run docker with NATS config file:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/home/matheus/nats-server.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/08959b2fce0deb2abea27e103f7f4426b7ed6f3ef64b214f713ebb993c2373e6/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/08959b2fce0deb2abea27e103f7f4426b7ed6f3ef64b214f713ebb993c2373e6/merged/nats-server.conf\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type. error Command failed with exit code 125.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create a [configuration file](https://docs.nats.io/nats-server/configuration) for NATS. And push it to the container as a Docker volume and set the `command` as `-c nats-server.conf`

**nats-server.conf**

```
max_payload: 4Mb
```

**Start container**

```
docker run -d -p 4222:4222 -v ~/nats-server.conf:/nats-server.conf nats -c /nats-server.conf
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer! I tried to do that but the payload do not change. When I start the container as you said it prints an error because there is the aprameter "-v" so I dropped it and the container started, is it really necessary and why ? Otherwise I continued testing without "-v" and still not changing the default value =( Do you know if there is another way to change it ? Thanks

Comment: I added the error it returns when I create the container as you said.

Comment: What kind of error? The payload exceeded?

Comment: The parameter -v is correct: https://i.imgur.com/Z2AmL11.png

Comment: Now it works! Thanks a lot, I just had to make some changes on my home dir

Comment: It works for me too. Thanks.