# Configure NATS max_payload on Kubernetes

Tags: javascript, kubernetes, nats.io

my problem is that I need to increase NATS max_payload in production environment but it uses Kubernetes and I have no idea how to do that, I tried to use ConfigMap but I had not success.

In local/dev environment it uses a NATS config file with docker so it works fine.

Way to make it works local: [NATS with moleculer. How can I change NATS max_payload value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65638631/nats-with-moleculer-how-can-i-change-nats-max-payload-value)

Code inside k8s/deployment.develop.yaml

```
(...)
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: nats
  namespace: develop
  labels:
    account: nats
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nats
  namespace: develop
  labels:
    app: nats
    service: nats
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 4222
      targetPort: 4222
  selector:
    app: nats
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nats-v1
  namespace: develop
  labels:
    app: nats
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nats
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nats
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nats
      containers:
        - image: 'nats:alpine'
          name: nats
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4222
      restartPolicy: Always
      tolerations: []
      affinity: {}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The payload value is hardcoded into the docker image (in the nats-server.conf file), so you cannot change it via a configmap. The only solution I found is to build my own nats image with a modified `nats-server.conf` file.

Here is how to do it.

1. First, select an image flavor from [the official repo](https://github.com/nats-io/nats-docker) and download the content (for example `Dockerfile` and `nats-server.conf` from [here](https://github.com/nats-io/nats-docker/tree/master/2.2.6/scratch)).
2. Modify the `nats-server.conf` file to change the `max_payload` value : just add the following line (this file is NOT in JSON format)

```
max_payload: 4Mb
```

3. Then build the image : `docker image build .`
4. Tag it, upload it to your own repo and use it instead of the official `nats` image

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using these [NATS Helm charts](https://github.com/nats-io/k8s/tree/master/helm/charts/nats#limits) and then use something like the following:

```yaml
nats:
  limits:
    maxPayload: "5mb"
```

You can find a full example here: https://github.com/nats-io/k8s/tree/master/helm/charts/nats#limits